# my type illegally extends DeleteResourceAction

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a type that extends `DeleteResourceAction`. Eclipse gives me following warning:

```
An anonymous type defined in mishanesterenko.changevisualizer.command.handler.DeleteResourceCommandHandler.execute(ExecutionEvent) illegally extends DeleteResourceAction
```

What is the reason for this warning?

**UPD**

I have following code which generates the warning:

```
DeleteResourceAction deleteAction = new org.eclipse.ui.actions.DeleteResourceAction(new CustomShellProvider(activeWindow)) {
            @Override
            public IStructuredSelection getStructuredSelection() {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) selectionService.getSelection();
                Object element = selection.getFirstElement();
                if (element instanceof CustomProject) {
                    return new StructuredSelection(((CustomProject) element).getProject());
                }
                return selection;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Where is the code that generates this warning?

Comment: you will get a better answer if you describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jeffrey, updated question with the code

Comment: @pstanton, updated question with the code

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Also, can you include the signature of DeleteResourceAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DeleteResourceAction javadoc there is an explicit request to NOT extend the class.

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.8M3-201110271800/testresults/reports/org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.8.0.v20111007-1312/org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.actions/DeleteResourceAction.java.html

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Factions%2FDeleteResourceAction.html) reveals that `DeleteResourceAction` is not meant to be subclassed. Anonymous classes are a subclass.